# Customize view record Spatie Shield plugin

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp

[Role & Permission page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEYet.png)
I use plugin Shield from spatie for manage role & permission, i want to customize view table like hide delete button, reformat date , or etc..

i expect to hide delete button, so user cant delete role.